# Laravel Mail::Send

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm looking to record the SMTP transaction for each sent email in laravel 4.1.

For example when I use the following code to send an email:

```
Mail::send('emails.any_view', $data, function($message) use ($user) {
    $message->from('server@example.com', 'PHP Code');
}
```

I would like to see something like:

```
[Resolving gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com...]
[Contacting gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.64.27]...]
[Connected]
220 mx.google.com ESMTP zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
EHLO Network-Tools.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [67.222.132.193]
VRFY test
252 2.1.5 Send some mail, I'll try my best zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
RSET
250 2.1.5 Flushed zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
EXPN test
502 5.5.1 Unimplemented command. zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
RSET
250 2.1.5 Flushed zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
MAIL FROM:<admin@Network-Tools.com>
250 2.1.0 OK zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<test@gmail.com>
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
[Address has been rejected]
RSET
250 2.1.5 Flushed zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection zd4si6046704obb.40 - gsmtp
[Connection closed]
```

I don't really care if this is in a log file or variable I can just dump when I need to. does anyone know how I can access this information?

I think I'm getting closer to my answer. If I replace the encription in app/config/mail.php to something invalid I get an error message like:

Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 220 but got code "500", with message "500 5.5.1 Unknown or unimplemented command "

I need a way of accessing the response codes even when they do not create an error.

Comment: The answer provided by the remote server is received after sending. You probably would have to catch return e-mails. I believe there is also a way to "attempt" an SMTP connection.

Comment: Laravel use swiftmailer vendor, maybe you should start looking for swift mailer and logs for this vendor

Comment: Switfmailer won't help you here, it only gives print_r($failures); back after sending.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Mail itself does not provide these details.

There is only the Log functionality, which writes all e-mails to your log files and does not send them to recipients. This is mainly for debugging and email content verification.

Mail::send() uses the configured mail daemon, which is your server or a remote server.

If you are using a remote, like Gmail, as SMTP server, you will not get access to these log details.

If it is you own server, go to the configured logs dir and catch the relevant log file.

- /var/log/maillog
- /var/log/mail.log
- /var/adm/maillog
- /var/adm/syslog/mail.log
- /etc/syslog.conf is your friend

When you have determined the file, use PHP to read it or `tail -f /var/log/maillog`.

`echo file_get_contents('/var/log/maillog');` :)

Comment: What about simple details such as "I was able to give the email to the smtp server?" Right now I have absolutely no idea if an email was successfully handed off to the mail server.

Comment: SwiftMailer: messages, messages send = numSent. $numSent = $mailer->send($message); printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.. It is working fine when i changed EMAIL_ENCRYPTION in mail.php. It was 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tps'), before I change it to 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),